# How can we sync one postgres database in rds to other postgres database in rds?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, synchronization, amazon-rds

There is one postgres database in rds. We need to sync it to another postgres database in rds.

I have connected one database with pg admin but not sure how to synchronise the database with the other one.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this a recurring task or a one time task?** If it's a one time thing, you can do a dump/backup and restore it to a new instance. If this is a recurring thing, then...

**Why do you want to replicate the data?** What is your actual goal? If it's for scaling, you should likely use the native RDS functionality for that. If it's for testing, then you will likely want to sanitize data as part of the copy.

As [smac2020](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435543/smac2020) said in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75461569/4106737), [AWS provides a migration service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) you can use for several use cases, but if this is a one-time thing, that is likely overkill. Just do a backup and restore that to another server.

You can also leverage [change-data-capture](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html) to [replicate data out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.CDC.html), but that will likely take a lot to get working well and will only be worth it in certain circumstances. We leverage CDC to copy data to our warehouse, for example. [Here is an example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/) that streams data to Kinesis. [Here is another example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-the-aws-database-migration-service-to-stream-change-data-to-amazon-kinesis-data-streams/) that streams to Kinesis using the migration service.

Comment: After thinking about that more --  I removed that answer for the reason you stated. It may be an over kill. Nice answer BTW.